# Бот отключается сам по себе

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-api

Буквально недавно возникла проблема.
У меня есть свой бот Discord.
Я его залил на VDS (ruvds(не реклама)).
Для его поддержания использую сессию `tmux`.
Так вот, бот иногда сам по себе уходит в оффлайн.
В консоли никаких проблем:

[image: вот скрин из консоли]

Вот принты консоли

```html
[DB] Vips database loaded sucefully
[DB] Gulags database loaded sucefully
loaded 29 commands
Loaded |disconnect| event file
Loaded |guildCreate| event file
Loaded |guildDelete| event file
Loaded |ready| event file
Started & logged as NervelBot#1335
Состою на 14 серверах.
```

И когда бот уходит в оффлайн, консоль выглядит именно так.
Никаких ошибок.
Может кто-то помочь?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Если никаких ошибок в консоли нет, быть может ваш хостинг "тушит" вашего бота? Не пробовали воспользоваться [nodemon](https://nodemon.io) ?

Comment: @MoloF, Спасибо! Обязательно попробую.

Comment: @MoloF, Всё таки не помогло. Спустя некоторое время, он опять оффнулся.

В консоли только:
Started & logged as NervelBot#1335
Состою на 14 серверах.
Started & logged as NervelBot#1335
Состою на 14 серверах.
Started & logged as NervelBot#1335
Состою на 14 серверах.
Started & logged as NervelBot#1335
Состою на 14 серверах.
Started & logged as NervelBot#1335
Состою на 14 серверах.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в этом причина, должна быть ошибка но... а вдруг озу не хватает? попробуйте установить pm2 и помониторить бота